# Can't find Workbook_BeforeClose Function in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I am trying to follow this[Tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuIADd_H9hM&list=PLS7iHfqXNVhK3yzd_4XS5k4zsvnu2mkJC) here. I can't find the function Workbook_BeforeClose in my Mac. But can't seem to find it.

Screenshot looks like this:[image].

It is not in the list. How do I activate it?

Any idea how I can find it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can't find the function Workbook_BeforeClose in my Mac

Er... That is because you are looking at the wrong place???? You have to be in the workbook module and not the worksheet module.

See screenshot

[image]

Comment: thanks. it solved my issue. but the one question: when you change to thisworkbook, it still doesn't show all the options like it does in windows. It seems to show the restricted options..

Answer (score 3):

You can code it like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    'ThisWorkbook Module code!

    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    'Me.Save is safer - if this workbook is closed programmatically 
    'then ActiveWorkbook may not be the same one
End Sub
```

Please see Mr Excel:
http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/170240-visual-basic-applications-before-close-save-workbook.html

Also:
Workbook.BeforeClose Event (Excel):
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194765.aspx

Comment: I am surprised at the upvote :)

Comment: If I wanted to downvote it.. I would have done it earlier :) You can still save your post by removing the line `I cannot find it either, however you can code it like so:`

Comment: Here is my + 1 for taking the feedback in the right manner :)

Comment: C# is not my forte but I will still have a look at it :)

Comment: You can use `Me.Save` from the workbook's module, it's more explicit.

Comment: You could add it as a comment `'or Me.Save`. There is a potential issue that if the workbook is closed programmatically then `ActiveWorkbook` may not be the same book.

Comment: @Yve I've edited it. Don't worry too much. Not much slips past SO. If we make a mistake we can tell very quickly by the negative rain that follows ;)